# regex to detect specific words

Tags: regex

How to match specific words that are not part of a word?

For example, I'd like the regex to detect the three "on" but not the one in "long".

**on** long **on** abc the **on**

When I use `(?: |^)the|on|of(?: |$)`, it detects the "on" in "long" as well which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Use this regex : `/\Won\W/`. Basicaly, you want a non-word character, 'on', then a non-word character

Comment: Thanks. This does not catch the first and last "on", though.

Comment: My bad, this one should work : `/\bon\b/` the `\b` are used to catch word boundaries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things here to mention:

- When you want to restrict a context for a group of words, always group them
- To match as a whole word, you need to use [word boundaries, `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

So, you need

```
\b(?:the|on|of)\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4zAMXw/1).

[image]

You can see on the diagram that the word boundaries now pertain to all the alternatives listed with `|` operator due to the fact they are all enclosed with a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense :)

Comment: Done. :) Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Could I ask you another question related to this? I am trying to group several of the matching words into a named group. For example, given `the on lol on the of`, I am looking for group A = `the on` and group B = `on the of`. I tried something like `(P<A>(\b(?:the|on|of)\b)*) lol (P<B>(\b(?:the|on|of)\b)*)` but it does not work.. :-/

Comment: @Ted You should match whitespace chars between words, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4zAMXw/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex :

```
/\bon\b/
```

The `\b` tokens are matching any word boundaries, would they be spaces, string start or end, etc...

So this is pretty straight forward : you need the word `on`, surrounded by word boundaries.